# Wordpress, admin_enqueue_scripts not loading all files in head

Tags: wordpress

I'm writing a plugin that uses 'admin_enqueue_scripts' to load css and js files.

I use the exact same method to load css and js.. But only the css is loaded in the head section, js files are loaded in the footer?

Can't figure out why?

The wp codex (https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts) at the example clearly states:
"In this example we are loading a javascript file in the **head** section of edit.php."

Here's my code:

```
    // add scripts and styles only available in admin
    add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'eman_add_admin_JS' ) ); 
    add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'eman_add_admin_CSS' ) );

public function eman_add_admin_CSS() {
    if(is_admin() && $_GET['page'] == 'enjoyit-management' || $_GET['page'] == 'management-settings'){              
        wp_register_style( 'eman-style-admin', plugins_url( '/css/eman-style-admin.css', __FILE__ ), array(), '1.0', 'all' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'eman-style-admin' );         
    }
}

public function eman_add_admin_JS() {
    if(is_admin() && $_GET['page'] == 'enjoyit-management' || $_GET['page'] == 'management-settings'){      
        // Load jQuery, just to be sure.        
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
        wp_register_script( 'eman-script-admin', plugins_url( '/js/eman-script-admin.js' , __FILE__ ), array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'eman-script-admin' );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only if you put true in the enqeue or register_script it will load in the header.

The 'best' place for jquery and javascript is to be loaded in the footer. Because it won't cause lag on your website.

But if you want it in the header you should use

```
wp_register_script( 'my-script', plugins_url( 'my-script.js' , __FILE__ ), array('jquery'), '1.0', false );
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script' );
```

Comment: Thanks Danny for your fast replay (damn...). It has to be false, when you want it to load in the head section, I'll mark your answer as the correct one.

Comment: Please edit your answer, change 'true' to 'false' in the register_script line. -- Edit -- Thanks, I have to wait 5 min, before i can accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

OMG, sorry, after posting I read the codex about 'wp_register_script', and there it was. The last parameter is a '$in_footer' boolean, which is set to true... aargh..